# Ubuntu Bionic(18.04) - KDE - Nvidia 418 / Prime-select needs 2 logout

Tags: drivers, nvidia, graphics, nvidia-optimus, nvidia-prime

Anybody knows that issue?

I installed nvidia 418 driver by driver repo. Everythink is normal when I used 390 driver in offical repo.

I can use my intel gpu switch naturaly. But when I tried to switch nvidia gpu "nvidia-smi" gonna work but it isnt rendering anythink and nvidia-settings give me only 2 option (Select intel , nvidia screen). If I logout and login one more time everythink is gonna working.

KDE neon - Kubuntu both have same issue. Dont tried any differend DE.

It isnt weird ?

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic

Comment: Same on kubuntu. Nothing changes.

Comment: Kubuntu is an official flavor and on-topic.  KDE Neon is neither Ubuntu, nor an official flavor of Ubuntu, thus off-topic for this site.  Use a KDE Neon forum, or SE's Unix & Linux Q&A site.

Comment: I can change title to kubuntu cuz I have that issue on both.

Comment: The paste will need to change too, package details in it are wrong for Kubuntu 18.04LTS

Comment: Please I need solution. Its working on 18.10 and 19.04 beta but I have this issue on 18.04